# is innerHTML with radio buttons safe?

Tags: javascript, security, innerhtml

So I know that using innerHTML with user input is not safe but I'm wondering if it's okay if you're using radio buttons, where the only user input is checked vs unchecked.

My JS looks like this:  `const topsButton = document.getElementById("tops"); topsButton.addEventListener("click", () => { chart.innerHTML = "<div>somehtml</div>"});`

this JS is embedded in a script tag in my HTML.

Can this be exploited?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Safely_inserting_external_content_into_a_page

Comment: The danger is not the user input. The danger is when you render someone ELSE's input on the page. So if you save user inputted HTML without sanitizing it and show it to another user, then that other user can be a victim of XSS if the first user has malicious intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that using innerHTML with user input is not safe

The issue that arises when using innerHTML with user input is that the document could be corrupted by a "bad" input. In a benign case, the user might accidentally paste something that messes up the page formatting; in the worst cases, an attacker may manipulate the user into inputting code that steals their credentials or performs privileged actions etc.

The risk comes from *unconstrained* user input rather than user input itself. If I have a text input whose contents get copied verbatim into the innerHTML of an element, that would generally be considered risky, or at least highly questionable. If the contents are run through a high quality HTML sanitizer before being added to the page, that would be significantly less risky.

In this case, you're just adding a known HTML payload depending on user input. This is not a risky behavior. For what it's worth, that particular snippet looks quite safe to me but I am not accredited as an HTML sanitizing library!

As an aside, innerHTML manipulation can be considered a bit of a "code smell" – partly because of the HTML injection security aspects, partly because it tends to make it harder to make sure that the document is "well formed", potential performance implications .... You might instead having that `<div>` within the document and hiding/revealing it with CSS and appropriate ARIA markup.

Answer (score 0):

Using innerHTML with radio buttons, where the only user input is checked vs unchecked, is relatively safer compared to scenarios where you're directly incorporating user input into innerHTML. However, there is always some degree of risk when using innerHTML, as it can potentially introduce cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities if not used carefully.

In your specific case, it seems that the content being injected into the innerHTML is a static string ("somehtml"), which should not present an immediate XSS risk since there is no user input being inserted. The risk would be higher if you were inserting the user input into the innerHTML, as it might allow an attacker to inject malicious scripts.

That being said, it's generally a good practice to avoid using innerHTML and opt for safer alternatives like textContent or the methods provided by the DOM API, such as createElement, createTextNode, and appendChild, to create and manipulate DOM elements.

Here's an example of how you could rewrite your code using the DOM API:

```
const topsButton = document.getElementById("tops");
topsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = "somehtml";
  chart.innerHTML = ""; // Clear the contents of the chart element
  chart.appendChild(div);
});
```

This way, you're using a safer approach to manipulate the DOM, reducing the risk of XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: textContent=someHTML will show the tags. That is likely not expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

In short, if the radio button is checked/unchecked with innerHTML, it is a safe option. But, it is always recommended to sanitize the user input and prevent dynamic HTML construction.